# trouble with Wordpress (Buddypress) localhost installation?

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, xampp, wordpress

I installed wordpress in localhost using Xampp and [Bitnami](http://bitnami.com/stack/xampp)

it works well at the begin and I install also Buddypress plugin and start working on the website .  Today however it suddenly stopped working.

I type `http://localhost/` in the browser  but nothing happens just a blanck white screen after the page achieve loading.

Joomla and phpbb are also installed and works well both , the problem is just for wordpress.

Please I need a help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your XAMPP server , both the mysql and php service and give it a try. It should work.

Access via `http://localhost:port` , Using the port that you have defined in your XAMPP settings.